# Проблема при установке модуля оплаты liqpay на Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Всем добрый день! Есть небольшой вопрос, так как первый раз столкнулся с установкой модуля оплаты `liqpay` на `Yii2`. Сначала все делал как было написано, а конкретно: выполнил команду `php composer require pistol88/yii2-liqpay "*"` , затем обновил , выполнив при этом команду `php composer update` Потом подключил в конфигурационный файл вот эти данные:

```
'modules' => [
    'liqpay' => [
        'class' => 'pistol88\liqpay\Module',
        'public_key' => 'iNNNNNNNNNNN',
        'private_key' => 'NzpRclCywaSOrm0LTpqDpPPlRDhoOQyIX1ISHjk',
        'currency' => 'UAH',
        'pay_way' => null,
        'version' => 3,
        'sandbox' => false,
        'language' => 'ru',
        'result_url' => '/page/thanks',
        'paymentName' => 'Оплата заказа',
        'orderModel' => 'pistol88\order\models\Order', //Модель заказа. Эта модель должна имплементировать интерфейс pistol88\liqpay\interfaces\Order. В момент списания денег будет вызываться $model->setPaymentStatus('yes').
    ],
    //...
],
```

Затем вывел виджет во `view`(в моем случае это страница `cart/order.php`):

```
<?=\pistol88\liqpay\widgets\PaymentForm::widget([
    'autoSend' => true,
    'orderModel' => $model,
    'description' => 'Оплата заказа'
]);?>
```

Но при этом постоянно выводит такую ошибку, что бы я не делал и исправлял:

> Class 'pistol88\liqpay\widgets\PaymentForm' not found

Кто то знает в чем причина, возможно где то что то недописал я? Буду благодарен за подсказку.

Comment: вы уверены что модуль установился? проверяли файл на его физическое существование?

Comment: нет, не проверял, щас проверю.спасибо за ответ

Comment: Я проверил на физическое существование, он есть

Comment: в каком месте выводит эту ошибку? какая строка, и что там,  Еще  найдите виджет и проверьте физическое существование PaymentForm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

смотрите , если вы говорите, что модуль корректно установился и все тип топ, то вам нужно проверить вот эту строку

```
<?=\pistol88\liqpay\widgets\PaymentForm::widget([
```

вы скопировали его с документации которая прилагается, но возможно ваша архитектура проекта отличается и т.п

Если вы пользуетесь phpStorm то он проидексирует проект...
Вверху документа попробуйте подключить PaymentForm  через use , ide должно увидеть данный модуль.
После уже будите выводить через PaymentForm::

и проверьте физически в paymentFrom  тот ли namespace там прописан?!